# 'Map' user input to specific variables

Tags: python

I am writing a small program in python, where the user will input parameters and the value to it. 
This basically should look like:

filter with "version" "2.0"

filter with "timer" "250"

To write the program I want to store all parameters in an array and the values also in one.

parameters = ["version", "timer"]

For the program I need to use specific strings for the parameters. 
The User types in "version", program uses "ancp.ver"

Now to my question. Is there an option how I can easily store and use the specific string like "ancp.ver"? When I started I used only an if function but since the parameters now are getting more I need a clean way to work with them.

Thank you for your help

If there are any questions open, please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get what you are trying to do, typically in Python you can use dictionaries to map between objects. You can use them even as switch-case is used in other languages (e.g. map strings to functions).

Something like this can work:

```
d = {"version": "ancp.ver",
     "foo": "bar"
    }

user_input = "version"
output = d[user_input]
```

Hopefully I captured what you were looking for.

Comment: I think you understood me. I will try it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe dictionaries are a viable option for you.

Instead of storing the information in two separate arrays, you can input a "key" that has a certain "value" to it.

Example :

```
NameOfDictionary = {'version':2.1,
                    'Key':"Value",
                    'GroupTime':1,
                    'fileName':"DefaultFileName",
                    'delays':[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    'waitForInputToClose':True}
```

To access the values associated with each key, you can do : `settings['key']`

This would return `'Value'`

You can find more information on dictionaries here :
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html